# Why do Eclipse use an older version of code when exporting a Runnable Jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar, eclipse-mars

I have a project that works perfectly fine when I run it in eclipse. However when I export it as a runnable Jar, it gives me an older version of the project, from a couple days ago.

I have no idea why or how it is exporting the older code and files that as far as I knew don't even exist any more.

I tried doing Project > Clean but it didn't work

Is this a known eclipse bug?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What steps are you taking to export it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general suggestions. Hopefully one or more of them will do the trick:

1. The most obvious one which should work is doing a project clean.

[image]

2. Manually delete the compiled java (ex: `foo.class`) from your project bin folder.
3. Delete the Refactoring History from within eclipse. Right click on the project > Properties > Refactoring History

[image]

4. If all above steps fail, you can create a new project and then copy & paste your code into new Java files.